# Detecting "#pragma warning(push)" without corresponding "#pragma warning(pop)"

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I recently found a header file which included the following, but didn't include a corresponding "pop" operation.

```
#pragma warning(push, 1)
#pragma warning(disable: 4503)
```

This had the effect of setting warning level to 1 for source files which include the header (we normally compile at warning level 3 with VS2013).

I'm looking for a way to detect mismatched push/pop operations so they can be removed from our code base.  Ideally the detection would be part of our build process so once removed, no new instances would creep into the code.

One option would be to preprocess the source files and parse the output looking for mismatches.  However, I'm wondering what other options might be available.

Any ideas?

Thanks!